# Python: What can I use to convert .pages to .ppt and .pages to .doc?

Tags: python, macos, ms-office, iwork

I'm trying to write a Python script to convert between those formats mentioned above, and I haven't been able to find a suitable library that is capable of doing this. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.pages` to `.ppt` part I'm not sure about (I'd assume you'd want a keynote file for doing that). However with the `.pages` to `.doc` part you might want to look into the [PyObjC Scripting Bridge](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/RubyPythonCocoa/Articles/UsingScriptingBridge.html) support interfacing with Pages. There is a guide which [looks at doing so with pages](http://www.mugginsoft.com/kosmictask/help/automation-python), changing the `.rtf` references to `.pages` and the `"SLDocumentTypeRichText"` to `"Microsoft Word 97 - 2004 document"` for doc support.

Comment: Good catch, thank you. I could shell out to convert .pages to .ppt, but I'm not certain that is the best Pythonic solution.